# Bootstrap session timeout - reset counter on mousemove

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, session-timeout

Bootstrap's [session timeout plugin](https://github.com/maxfierke/jquery-sessionTimeout-bootstrap) doesn't seem to support resetting the count towards session end, whenever the user moves the mouse. So, for instance, the default 15 mins `warnAfter` value will pop the message 15 mins afters login, regardless of user activity.

```
        $.sessionTimeout({
        logoutUrl:AppData.paths.appPath + "/logout",
        redirUrl:AppData.paths.appPath + "/logout",
        warnAfter:10000 
        // will trigger the popup after 10 secs regardless of user activity
     });
```

I haven't found any option that might tackle this issue. Is there way to overcome it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout orange hill's fork which was created because of the same problem.

http://www.orangehilldev.com/?p=101

https://github.com/orangehill/bootstrap-session-timeout

Answer (score 1):

Use the next property:

```
ignoreUserActivity: false
```